# javascript setinterval get blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function which is called every 45 secs and later based on the status from server it get stopped. Say if the server sends poll = false then I am clearing the interval otherwise the poll will proceed.

In some situation , the poll is getting stopped without clear interval. This is inconsistent . What could be the root cause for this issue.

```
tChk = setInterval("pollStatus(true)", 45000);

pollStatus(userInitiated){
....
....
....
}
```

When server returns poll= false then do

```
clearInterval(tChk);
```

Thanks.

Comment: _root cause for this issue_ We need to see comprehensive code rather than a mere skeleton

Comment: This is doing a server GET request . It is not required here.

Comment: Could be just about anything.. Maybe the whole page is reloaded?  Maybe the server *is* returning poll=false.  Maybe you have some other code that calls the function, but doesn't pass userInitiated or some other way tchk is cleared.

Comment: So ..if someone call this function without "userInitiated" will block the subsequent polls? .